# Replace string if it meets any condition values in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas DataFrame and would like to delete the sub-string in all values if it meets the condition that the string = 'test', 'tests', 'testing', 'orig' and 'new'. I can use str.replace() to replace the value for a single string condition, but unsure how to do include additional conditions to test for and replace.

See below:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008'],
                     'color_value': ['blue_test', 'red', 'yellow_tests', 'orange_orig',
                     'blue_new','red', 'blue_testing', 'orange']})
```

For one condition, I can do:

```
term = 'test'
df_1['color_value'] = df_1['color_value'].str.replace(term,'')
```

How can I extend it to include removing 'tests', 'testing', 'orig' and 'new'?

Comment: I also have suffixes such as "orig" and "new" along with "test", "tests" and "testing" that need to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
term = 'test(s|ing)?'
df_1['color_value'] = df_1['color_value'].str.replace(term, '', regex=True)
print(df_1)
```

**Output**

```
    id color_value
0  001       blue_
1  002         red
2  003     yellow_
3  004      orange
4  005        blue
5  006         red
6  007       blue_
7  008      orange
```

From the documentation on [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

> **pat** str or compiled regex
> String can be a character sequence or regular expression.

**UPDATE**

For including `"new", "origin"` you could do use another regex:

```
term = 'test(s|ing)?|new|orig'
df_1['color_value'] = df_1['color_value'].str.replace(term, '', regex=True)
print(df_1)
```

**Output**

```
    id color_value
0  001       blue_
1  002         red
2  003     yellow_
3  004     orange_
4  005       blue_
5  006         red
6  007       blue_
7  008      orange
```

**General Solution**

If you have many words I suggest you use a library such as [trrex](https://trrex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html) it will build a regular expression from a set of words:

```
import pandas as pd
import trrex as tx

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008'],
                     'color_value': ['blue_test', 'red', 'yellow_tests', 'orange_orig',
                                     'blue_new', 'red', 'blue_testing', 'orange']})

term = tx.make(['test', 'tests', 'testing', 'orig', 'new'], prefix="", suffix="")
df_1['color_value'] = df_1['color_value'].str.replace(term, '', regex=True)
print(df_1)
```

**Output**

```
    id color_value
0  001       blue_
1  002         red
2  003     yellow_
3  004     orange_
4  005       blue_
5  006         red
6  007       blue_
7  008      orange
```

The pattern for the given example is:

```
term = tx.make(['test', 'tests', 'testing', 'orig', 'new'], prefix="", suffix="")
print(term)
```

**Output** *(pattern build by trrex)*

```
(?:test(?:ing|s)?|new|orig)
```

**DISCLAIMER**

I'm the author of [trrex](https://pypi.org/project/trrex/)

Comment: What if the other strings don't have the base word test? I also have suffixes such as "orig" and "new" along with "test", "tests" and "testing" that need to be removed.

Comment: Include a better example in the question and the expected output

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: @ASsoccer9 Updated the answer.

Comment: To confirm, this will not leave any trailing whitespaces correct? Otherwise, looks great to me. Thank you!